# localhost refuse to connect

Tags: plutus

I recently finish the whole pionner program video and try to do it by myself.
I used wsl2+debian to set up the enviroment, but after I build everything. it said I can access the playground through localhost:8009, I tried multiple times. always got refused.
anyone got the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use https, not http.

https://localhost:8009

Comment: thank you.  I used https.. not sure why. I shutdown wsl2 and restarted it, it works...

Comment: if this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer